# XNA Controls Rotation in Addition to Camera/Model

Tags: c#, rotation, controls, xna, monogame

Before I start: I tried gamedev.stackexchange and nobody replied so I thought I'd test my luck here :)

I'm relatively new to 3D programming and I'm trying to make a game where the player can control a character around a maze.

My current problem isn't really getting the mouse to be centre and reading it to rotate the camera - although I'd like to in the future, right now it's getting the WASD movement to also rotate, I assume this means I'd need to rotate the axis. I've been trying for about 1-2 hours looking around, some say to use Quaternions and others Matrices, but I haven't been able to get anything to work so far. To clarify, when I hold W, it moves forward. But if I then rotate the camera to look to the right and hold W, it'll move left of the camera <--- I want to fix this if possible

I'm very lost at what to do or how best to do it, I'll provide my Camera class and Game1 class, although I'll warn you - I'm not very good at laying things out nicely. I'm not a highly experiences programmer so asking me to apply knowledge to my project may take me a while to get right, thanks :D

```
    public class Camera
{
    float angle = 1f;
    float currentAngle;
    public Vector3 cameraPosition;
    public Vector3 cameraTarget;
    public Matrix worldMatrix { get; set; }
    public Matrix viewMatrix { get; set; }
    public Matrix projectionMatrix { get; set; }
    public Matrix rotationMatrix;
    Matrix playerPos;
    Matrix movement;
    Vector3 position;

    public void SetMovement(Matrix inMovement)
    {
        movement = inMovement;
    }

    public void SetPosition(Vector3 inPosition)
    {
        position = inPosition;
    }

    public Camera(GraphicsDevice graphics, Vector3 inTarget)
    {
        rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(0f));
        cameraTarget = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        cameraPosition = new Vector3(0f, -1f, 3.5f);
        playerPos = Matrix.CreateScale(0.01f) *
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
        projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45f),
                                                    graphics.DisplayMode.AspectRatio,
                                                    0.03f, 100f);
        worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateWorld(inTarget, Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up);

        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, inTarget, Vector3.Up);
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        if(Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            currentAngle += angle;
            rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(currentAngle)) * rotationMatrix;
            currentAngle = 0;
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            currentAngle += angle * -1;
            rotationMatrix = rotationMatrix * Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(currentAngle));
            currentAngle = 0;
        }
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(cameraPosition.X + position.X, cameraPosition.Y + position.Y + 1.02f,   //FIRST PERSON CAMERA
            position.Z + 0.013f), cameraTarget + position + new Vector3(0f,1f,0f), Vector3.Up) * rotationMatrix;             
        //viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, Vector3.Up);                                        //MAP VIEW CAMERA

    }

}
```

Here's Game1

```
    public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Model map, player;
    Camera playerCamera;
    Vector3 playerPosition;
    Matrix playerCurrentPosition, cameraCurrentPosition;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        player = Content.Load<Model>("ball2");
        playerPosition = new Vector3(-0.84f, 0.86f, 0.02f);
        playerCamera = new Camera(GraphicsDevice, new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f));
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        map = Content.Load<Model>("newMap");


    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        playerCamera.SetMovement(playerCurrentPosition);
        playerCamera.SetPosition(playerPosition);
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            playerPosition.Y += 0.01f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            playerPosition.X -= 0.003f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            playerPosition.Y -= 0.003f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            playerPosition.X += 0.003f;
        playerCurrentPosition =
            Matrix.CreateScale(0.01f) *
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(playerPosition);
        cameraCurrentPosition = Matrix.CreateTranslation(playerPosition - new Vector3(0f, 0.1f, 0f));
        playerCamera.Update();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
                effect.World = world;
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Crimson);

        DrawModel(map, playerCamera.worldMatrix, playerCamera.viewMatrix, playerCamera.projectionMatrix);
        DrawModel(player, playerCamera.worldMatrix * playerCurrentPosition, playerCamera.viewMatrix, playerCamera.projectionMatrix);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a good tip for you: use Unity instead.

Comment: @Aybe I would, but it's for a project where we are being marked on the complexity of the project. Hence, XNA would get me much better points overall since it is more complex to implement features in than unity :)

Comment: Here's a not so new example (untested): https://github.com/patteri/XNA-FPS and even though you won't use Unity it doesn't mean you can't take inspiration from it, such as https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html.

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously different approaches to this, so this might not be the most elegant:

Let's assume that you store your camera rotation as an angle `rotationY` (you will need a second angle, but that probably won't influence the walking direction).

I assume that you currently have some code like this:

```
if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * elapsedTime;
```

What we now want to do is rotate that direction vector the same amount we rotated the camera. We can use Matrix transformations for that (writing the rotation with sin and cos would be faster, but as this only runs once per frame, that should not be a major concern):

```
Matrix rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationY);
Vector3 forward = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), rotation);
if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    position += forward * elapsedTime;
```

That's basically it. For backward movement, use -forward and for sideways motion, rotate a second vector using the same matrix.

There are different ways of doing this: You can compute the forward and sideways vector from the camera's point of view (I think it is quite fast to get them from the view matrix). That will probably be faster, but once again, performance shouldn't matter too much here.